# PHP Image Upload Strange Issue

Tags: php, file-upload

```
<?
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$url = 'http://www.connectedcampus.org/ckeditor/images/uploads/';

if (($_FILES['upload'] == "none") OR (empty($_FILES['upload']['name'])) )
{
   $message = "No file uploaded.";
}
else if ($_FILES['upload']["size"] == 0)
{
   $message = "The file is of zero length.";
}
else if (($_FILES['upload']["type"] != "image/pjpeg") AND ($_FILES['upload']["type"] != "image/jpeg") AND ($_FILES['upload']["type"] != "image/png"))
{
   $message = "The image must be in either JPG or PNG format. Please upload a JPG or PNG instead.";
}
else if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 1000000){
    $message = "File size too big!";
}
else if(file_exists($url.$_FILES["file"]["name"]))
  {
  $message=$_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
  }
else if (!is_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']["tmp_name"]))
{
   $message = "Invalid File!";
}
else {
  $message = "success!";
  $move = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], $url.$_FILES['upload']['name']);
  echo $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']."<br>";
  echo $url.$_FILES['upload']['name'];
  if(!$move)
  {
     $message = "Error moving uploaded file.";
  }
  $url = $url.$_FILES['upload']['name'];
}
 echo $message;
 </script>";
 }
 ?>
```

This prints "Error moving uploaded file"
Which means move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], $url.$_FILES['upload']['name'])
returns false. But I am 500% sure that i have created http://www.connectedcampus.org/ckeditor/images/uploads/ folder properly.... then why is there an error?

Ok, now changed to:

```
$url = 'bloguploads/';

    if (($_FILES['upload'] == "none") OR (empty($_FILES['upload']['name'])) )
    {
       $message = "No file uploaded.";
    }
    else if ($_FILES['upload']["size"] == 0)
    {
       $message = "The file is of zero length.";
    }
    else if (($_FILES['upload']["type"] != "image/pjpeg") AND ($_FILES['upload']["type"] != "image/jpeg") AND ($_FILES['upload']["type"] != "image/png"))
    {
       $message = "The image must be in either JPG or PNG format. Please upload a JPG or PNG instead.";
    }
else if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 1000000){
       $message = "File size too big!";
}
else if(file_exists($url.$_FILES["file"]["name"]))
    {
       $message=$_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
    }
    else if (!is_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']["tmp_name"]))
    {
       $message = "Invalid File!";
    }
    else {
       $message = "";
       $move = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], $url.$_FILES['upload']['name']);
       if(!$move)
       {
           $message = "Error moving uploaded file.";
       }
       $url = $url.$_FILES['upload']['name'];
       }
echo $message;
</script>";
?>
```

Now the thing is, it says "already exists". Why? I can see via the ftp client that file has not been uploaded

Comment: Read/Write permissions maybe?

Comment: @hjpotter92  chmod($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], 777);       
$message = "success!";
$move = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], $url.$_FILES['upload']['name']);      & changed permissions of uploads folder as well... nothing works

Comment: The fact that it says "already exists", not "Filename.jpg already exists" should be a hint...

Answer (score 1):

`move_uploaded_file` works on filesystem, not on urls.

instead of `$url` in

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], $url.$_FILES['upload']['name']);
```

use filesystem path, ie:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], "/home/www/uploads/".$_FILES['upload']['name']);
```

Comment: $url = '/ckeditor/images/uploads/';
still shows error uploading file! :-/

Comment: If you are trying to use relative path, remove `/` from the beginning. But better idea would be to spend some time and learn about absolute/relative path, current working directory and how to deal with them in PHP.

Comment: See the edit in the question above. I corrected the path. 
Now very strangely it says "already exists"

Comment: Try refreshing file list in your ftp client, maybe it is already there. Also you should use your own file names (change spaces to underscores, add upload timestamp etc.) and check if file exists before trying to move it to uploads folder.